# Is it possible to update records via Linq-to-sql from a view?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I dragged a view onto my `dbml` file and I am retrieving records from it.  Upon modifying the records and calling `context.SubmitChanges()` no changes are sent back to the database.  Upon debugging I saw that my `context.ViewName.IsReadOnly` is `true`.

Is there any way to change this?  I can run sql update statements just fine in SSMS against the view, so I am unaware of why this wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manually identifying the primary key in the dbml worked for me - just select the field that is mapped to the primary key from the source table and in its properties change 'Primary Key' to true.